# lmfit - best and init fit do not correspond to report

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

I am trying to fit data with Python library *lmfit*. In the data, there are two gaussian functions, the second (LO) higher than the first (TO). The code follows:

```
TOmod = GaussianModel(prefix="TO_")
LOmod = GaussianModel(prefix="LO_")
TOmod.set_param_hint('TO_center', min = 265, max = 270)
TOmod.set_param_hint('TO_amplitude', min = 3e3, max = 7e3)
TOmod.set_param_hint('TO_sigma', min = 0.1, max = 5)
LOmod.set_param_hint('LO_center', min = 280, max = 310)
LOmod.set_param_hint('LO_amplitude', min = 2e4, max = 4e4)
LOmod.set_param_hint('LO_sigma', min = 0.1, max = 8)
pars = TOmod.guess(y, x=x)
pars += LOmod.guess(y, x=x)
mod = TOmod + LOmod
out  = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)
print(out.fit_report())

plt.figure("Fitting")
plt.plot(x, y, "bo")
plt.plot(x, out.init_fit, 'k--')
plt.plot(x, out.best_fit, 'r-')
plt.xlabel(r"k [cm$^{-1}$]")
plt.ylabel(r"Intensity")
plt.xlim(250,325)
plt.ylim(-1e3,3e4)
plt.show("Fitting")
```

I can produce this graph:

[image]

*lmfit* also produces following report:

```
[[Model]]
    (Model(gaussian, prefix='TO_') + Model(gaussian, prefix='LO_'))
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # function evals   = 30
    # data points      = 576
    # variables        = 6
    chi-square         = 2534929941.545
    reduced chi-square = 4447245.511
    Akaike info crit   = 8823.259
    Bayesian info crit = 8849.395
[[Variables]]
    TO_sigma:       0.14748432 +/- 0        (0.00%) (init= 0.1)
    TO_center:      270        +/- 0        (0.00%) (init= 270)
    TO_amplitude:   3000       +/- 0        (0.00%) (init= 3000)
    TO_fwhm:        0.34729903 +/- 0        (0.00%)  == '2.3548200*TO_sigma'
    TO_height:      8114.94309 +/- 0        (0.00%)  == '0.3989423*TO_amplitude/max(1.e-15, TO_sigma)'
    LO_sigma:       0.25064604 +/- 0        (0.00%) (init= 0.1)
    LO_center:      292.364593 +/- 0        (0.00%) (init= 292.3646)
    LO_amplitude:   24876.9938 +/- 0        (0.00%) (init= 20000)
    LO_fwhm:        0.59022631 +/- 0        (0.00%)  == '2.3548200*LO_sigma'
    LO_height:      39595.6185 +/- 0        (0.00%)  == '0.3989423*LO_amplitude/max(1.e-15, LO_sigma)'
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
```

At first, final and initial LO_amplitudes do not correspond to the ones in report (f.e. you can see, that initial is 2e4, but in the graph it is at least 5e4). How come?

Secondly, I was expecting that the fit would be better, while all bounds are set.

### EDIT 1 - data added

I have posted the full script, only with which is missing is loading the data:

```
x, y = np.genfromtxt("data.txt", unpack=True)
```

And here are the data:

```
3.235230000000000246e+02 8.074899999999997817e+02
3.217950000000000159e+02 7.387500000000000000e+02
3.200659999999999741e+02 8.103400000000001455e+02
3.183369999999999891e+02 9.050399999999999636e+02
3.166080000000000041e+02 1.176100000000000364e+03
3.148790000000000191e+02 1.483189999999999600e+03
3.131490000000000009e+02 1.729449999999999818e+03
3.114189999999999827e+02 2.281949999999999818e+03
3.096890000000000214e+02 2.486050000000000182e+03
3.079580000000000268e+02 2.867739999999999782e+03
3.062269999999999754e+02 3.205949999999999818e+03
3.044950000000000045e+02 4.065239999999999782e+03
3.027629999999999768e+02 5.081539999999999964e+03
3.010310000000000059e+02 6.767100000000000364e+03
2.992989999999999782e+02 9.268700000000000728e+03
2.975659999999999741e+02 1.334320000000000073e+04
2.958319999999999936e+02 1.946429999999999927e+04
2.940989999999999895e+02 2.552240000000000146e+04
2.923650000000000091e+02 2.720209999999999854e+04
2.906309999999999718e+02 2.314690000000000146e+04
2.888960000000000150e+02 1.642840000000000146e+04
2.871610000000000014e+02 1.048929999999999927e+04
2.854259999999999877e+02 6.923909999999999854e+03
2.836899999999999977e+02 4.836300000000000182e+03
2.819540000000000077e+02 3.501239999999999782e+03
2.802169999999999845e+02 2.686470000000000255e+03
2.784809999999999945e+02 2.227590000000000146e+03
2.767440000000000282e+02 1.781840000000000146e+03
2.750059999999999718e+02 1.582319999999999709e+03
2.732679999999999723e+02 1.520989999999999782e+03
2.715299999999999727e+02 2.011989999999999782e+03
2.697919999999999732e+02 3.021930000000000291e+03
2.680529999999999973e+02 4.754640000000000327e+03
2.663140000000000214e+02 5.088010000000000218e+03
2.645740000000000123e+02 3.515579999999999927e+03
2.628340000000000032e+02 2.159310000000000400e+03
2.610939999999999941e+02 1.190029999999999745e+03
2.593530000000000086e+02 7.985300000000002001e+02
2.576120000000000232e+02 5.780700000000001637e+02
2.558710000000000093e+02 4.897800000000002001e+02
2.541289999999999907e+02 3.914800000000000182e+02
2.523870000000000005e+02 3.046999999999998181e+02
2.506450000000000102e+02 3.270000000000000000e+02
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get pretty decent looking results by following the advice I gave and providing initial values and not imposing constraints. Did you try that?

FWIW, I get even better results using a Lorentzian function for the wider `LO` peak. Try this:

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel, LorentzianModel
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.genfromtxt("data.txt", unpack=True)

TOmod = GaussianModel(prefix="TO_")
LOmod = LorentzianModel(prefix="LO_")
mod = TOmod + LOmod

pars = mod.make_params(TO_center=268, TO_sigma=2., TO_amplitude=50000,
                       LO_center=292, LO_sigma=4., LO_amplitude=50000)

out  = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)
print(out.fit_report())
```

For the alleged difference between graph report:

As you might have read in the documentation (http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html,  `amplitude` is the multiplier in front of the **unit normalized** Gaussian function, it is not the largest value the function will take.  OTOH, the Parameter `LO_height` and `TO_height` are reported and will be the maximum value of the functions. Similarly, `sigma` is variance not the Full-Width-Half-Maximum, but that is also reported.

Comment: I tried to add initial values before I posted the data, but it still did not work. I am used to call "height" "amplitude" and in this was the error. Removing these bad constraints for amplitude and adding initial guess solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That does look like it should work better to me.  I would recommend two things:

1. give explicit initial guesses by setting param values (especially for `TO_center` and `TO_amplitude` that are away from the bounds).
2. relax the bounds some - this fit should be easy, and I don't think the bounds are really necessary.

If those don't solve it, post the data and full script.

Comment: I have posted the data, you can try if it works for you with these. Still, this does not answer why is there difference between what is in the graph and what is in the report. I still think that values for best fit should be those in the record (same for initial values).